# Different Tooltip Hover within checkbox elements

Tags: html, css, reactjs, tooltip, use-effect

I have a checkbox with 6 elements, consisting of an icon, text and an information icon.
You can imagine like this:

- "icon" "text" "i"
- ...

I now want to display additional information when i hover over the information icon "i".
I gave the different information icon img class names, like "className=info1", ...
What I know tried to approach was with useEffect and creating an Array consisting of these classNames of the information icon images. In the nextstep I tried to implement a for-loop so that when a certain icon/ obj.onmouseover the text gets displayed. It would actually just help me to see if this is the right approach and how this for-loop would look like.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [react-tooltip](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-tooltip) to achieve the effect you want!